# Positioning two div on the same height and position

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have two div, first has width 30% of parent div, second has 70%. Both have different height. Code below displays me screen like at left side.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="div1">...</div>
    <div id="div2">...</div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want to get screen like right side. Both divs are on the same level, and have equal height, which is equals height of longer div. What should I write in my CSS code?

CSS file:

```
#parent {
}

#div1 {
    width: 30%;
}

#div2 {
    width: 70%;
```

}

Comment: We'll need to see your code in order to tell you what to change...

Comment: Please include your CSS.

Comment: Did you get it sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value of one (or both) of your div's to float: left. This causes any content to wrap around the object and the object sits on the left of the content.

```
#div1{
    float: left
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Comment: It's generally frowned upon to reference w3schools... Use this link as a better resource for learning about `floats` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: This doesn't solve the OPs question. He wants equal height on both div's.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jsFiddle that does what I think you're looking for. Both divs are on the same level, and have equal height (determined by `#div2`) as requested.

http://jsfiddle.net/QxvWr/4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#div1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:30%;
    height: 100%; 
    background: yellow;
}
#div2 {
    margin-left:30%;
    width:70%;
    height: 200px; /* change to whatever you want, or remove and have the div's content dictate the size. Note, overflow:hidden was added below for this very reason */
    background: orange;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code it works

```
<style>

#wrapper
{
margin:0px auto;
padding:0px;
width:1000px;

       }
#div1
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:250px;
float:left;
height:500px;
background-color:red;
}

#div2
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:750px;
height:500px;
float:right;
background-color:blue;
        }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">...</div>
    <div id="div2">...</div>
</div>
```

And below is the fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/QxvWr/5/